# How to choose an ally

Tags: rise-of-nations

I'm doing the Alexander the great campaing, and I'm currently playing the Megale Hellas scenario. The first battle objective is to choose an ally. I can click all the capitals to knows they're bonuses, but I don't understand how to choose my ally.

I've tried to propose an alliance through the diplomatic view, but every time I propose an alliance and send the correct ammount of ressources, the AI always reject my offer. There isn't much information in the battle objectives that could help me understand how to do it properly.

Comment: I'm new to Arquade, so if there is something let me know. I can post screenshot too if it can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried that scenario a few times with Rise of Nations Gold (the CD based version) and I had no trouble allying with nations. Make sure you're sending the 400 metal and not demanding it. That's a mistake I've made a few times. Also make sure you're sending it as part of the proposal. I was playing on moderate difficulty, at higher difficulties you may need to send more.

Here's what my screen looked like before I sent the request. After pressing the PROPOSE button the request was accepted immediately.

[image: Example of all negotiation screen]

I'm not sure I've ever played this particular scenario. I believe I just overran this province on the strategic map both times when I played the Alexander campaign. You'll want to try do this whenever you can. With neutral provinces like this one it's not that hard to do, but you might have to plan a turn or two in advance.

Comment: I feel so stupid at the moment! Thanks a lot I was indeed demanding instead of sending a tribute. Confirmed with the tribute they accepted and I can continue my scenario!